# What's the difference between IdentityResources OpenId, Email and Profile?

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4, openid

Reading the Identity server docs at 'https://docs.identityserver.io/en/3.1.0/topics/resources.html',
I am confused with IdentityResources. There are

- IdentityResources.OpenId()
- IdentityResources.Email()
- IdentityResources.Profile()

First of all what is OpenId() in this context? What are the differences between these three? For my case, my users are able to login with their email or username. Which should I use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**OpenId**, **Email** and **Profile** are **scopes**, things that the client application can ask IdentityServer for.

These three scopes will then map to claims that then will end up in the Id-Token

The openid scope is a special scope that always must be included and that will one ask for the users (sub) unique identifier (userid). the Email will ask for the email details and the profile scope will ask for the profile details (webpage, gender...)

Just like this picture below shows. The requested scopes will control what will end up in the ID-token and access-token.

[image]

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic:
[IdentityServer – IdentityResource vs. ApiResource vs. ApiScope](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/02/identityserver-identityresource-vs-apiresource-vs-apiscope/)

Comment: Thank you for the clear and consice answer!